# Trouble understanding how to create a Join & Require query

Tags: mysql

So, I guess I should explain what I mean by a `Join & Require Query` as this probably isn't the correct term. For this question I set up a very simple subset of tables that would be out of a wireframe for a video game. I apologise in advance, SQLFiddle isn't working right now.

```
CREATE TABLE reqs (
    crafted_id INT, item_id INT );

CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT, name VARCHAR(30) );

CREATE TABLE crafted (
    id INT, name VARCHAR(30) );
```

With these tables, I also created some sample data. I didn't use auto_increment in these tables so you could have a better visual.

```
INSERT INTO items (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Herbs');
INSERT INTO items (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Health Potion');
INSERT INTO items (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Leather');
INSERT INTO items (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Sticks');

INSERT INTO crafted (id, name) VALUES (101, 'Cured Leather');
INSERT INTO crafted (id, name) VALUES (102, 'Tea');

INSERT INTO reqs (crafted_id, item_id) VALUES (101, 1);
INSERT INTO reqs (crafted_id, item_id) VALUES (101, 3);
INSERT INTO reqs (crafted_id, item_id) VALUES (102, 1);
```

In this example I have setup a very minimalistic example of a crafting system in a game, where a crafted item requires other items.

I need to create a query in which I can pull all of the available values from the `crafted` table based on the `items` that I have. For example, based on the data above, I would do the following:

```
requestCraftableItems(itemArray) {
    // Execute query based on array here
};

requestCraftableItems([1, 2, 3])
```

This should execute a query stating that the user has items `1, 3, & 4` and try to find a `crafted` entry where all of the `reqs.item_id` for `reqs.crafted_id` are met in the item array. In this example nothing should be returned, because the crafted_id for cured leather requires items `1 & 3` and the crafted_id for `tea` requires item `1`

So if the user executed the following:

```
requestCraftableItems([1, 3, 4]);
```

It should return the crafted entry for `Cured Leather` AND `Tea` as the user supplied `1 & 3` to the query.

This is not my originally use case and is just an example to get the point of what I'm trying to do across on a very simple scale.

EDIT: To clairfy, if the value (1) is passed to the query, `Cured Leather` should not appear in the results, as Cured Leather requires BOTH 1 and 3.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what you mean, the sequences are shared based on the supplied parameters. Only supplying `1` will return `Tea`, but supplying `1 & 3` will Supply both `Tea & Cured Leather`. Not sure why/how i would separate these since they are also together.

Comment: @Strawberry I understand that you're suggesting a way to make it clearer, I just don't understand your suggestion. That's all.  Good point on the id column. Thanks.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, done.

Comment: Fixed it again. Whoops.

Comment: Here's another example to consider: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,416701,416795#msg-416795

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what you are looking for, but a simple join should return the result you want:

```
SELECT crafted.name
FROM items
JOIN reqs
ON reqs.item_id = items.id
JOIN crafted
ON crafted.id = reqs.crafted_id
WHERE items.id in (1,3,4)
GROUP BY crafted.id
```

This would return the results in your examples.

*Not tested, may contain typos*

Comment: I need to return data from the `crafted` table where the all of the `reqs.item_id` for `reqs.crafted_id` are supplied in the set.

Comment: I was able to make modifications to this Query to work the correct way around, however if only `IN (1)` is passed, the results `Tea` AND `Cured Leather` show up, however, Cured leather should only show up if bother 1 AND 3 are supplied.

Comment: @Hobbyist 'HAVING COUNT(*) = number of arguments in IN' or some variation of that. If you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Hobbyist Did you post the wrong link? Similar query, but different data set !?!?!